# Stop LINQ to SQL caching

Tags: asp.net, linq, linq-to-sql

The database query run on SQL server (and the actual linq query using SQL Debugger http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/07/31/linq-to-sql-debug-visualizer.aspx) 
show correct data.
The object returned shows old data.
How do I clear it?
Both are doing a select

```
        Dim s As New StaffRecord
        Dim q = From staff As StaffRecord In db.StaffRecords _
                Where staff.Employee_Number = u.AssignmentNo _
                Select staff
        s = q.First
```

There is a possibility of 2 staff records with the same employee number, hence using .First instead of .Single

Comment: Seems you have to shut down VS2008 and the browser for it to clear.

Comment: Just noticed if I kill the aspnet worker process on my PC in task manager it clears the cache.

Comment: Do you create the context object (the db variable, in your case) before executing this select or is it stored somewhere and you reuse it?

Comment: The context is declared as:  Public Shared db As New ESRdbDataContext(ESRdatacleanseConnectionStr)

Is this ok? I am reusing it several times in a helper class containing updates and inserts, etc.

Comment: If the context object is created and constantly reused, it's going to display the cached data it has stored. Where exactly is the db object declared? Is there a special reason it's declared as static?

Answer (score 1):

You should create and destroy the datacontext per request. It is designed for that pattern and creates quickly and will prevent stale data.